# What if gravitational force was strongest force rather than the Strong force

Tags: physics, gravity, strong-force

Gravity is the weakest of the fundamental forces of universe but along with electromagnetism tends to dominate most of the macro world phenomenon.

But what would happen if the force of gravitation were the strongest force in the universe. Would it be ever possible for this universe to exist of gravity would cause every single thing in existence to collapse into black holes and soon evaporate filling the universe with nothing but radiation. Also what if all of these forces were of equal strength with no one being clearly stronger at scales of less than $ 10^{-9} $m

Comment: This is a hard question to answer without knowledge of the subject. It might be better to ask in Physics, but it also seems like a pretty dumb question. If everything is a black hole then you're dealing with the unknown, but known enough to say it's silly to think the world would be anything like what it is. I don't think it's too broad or in need of closing, but not a very good question.

Comment: I removed the hard-science tag. That's a request for citations of scientific papers, equations, etc. in any answer, and I seriously doubt those would *exist* for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Check out *Raft*, by Stephen Baxter. It paints a vivid picture of human life in a universe where gravity is "a billion" times stronger than it is in our universe, where gravity is the strongest force on the atomic scale which allows for "gravitic chemistry", and where the average human has a decent gravitational field of their own. Life exists in nebulae surrounding black holes, and stars short-lived events a mile across. Really interesting stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Usually I vote to close "what if constant X were changed to be Y" questions because the universe is always "the universe is almost completely different than everything you would expect," but it sounds like Stephen Baxter actually explored what that "completely different" might look like!  I generally trust his books to have a pretty sound scientific basis (as far as fictional literature goes).

Comment: @CortAmmon It was his first novel. Not unexpectedly he has written better subsequently. It is a good exploration of the possibilities. Baxter takes his background as a physicist seriously in his fiction. So they're usually sound scientifically. You might enjoy reading it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities with your premise of gravity being the strongest force of all the 4 fundamental forces.

**1- If gravity were as strong as the strong nuclear force and SNF were as weak as gravity**

Well. Atoms wouldn't exist as we know them. Simple as that. And yes, the universe would indeed fall back into one gigantic singularity (aka black hole). Life would be extremely different to take hold anywhere atoms themselves would not exist for long. Also, Schwarzchild radii would be much larger than they are now, meaning that it would be very easy for stars (and maybe even planets!) to collapse into black holes. However, keep in mind that *stars* refers to a large chunk of matter of current stellar mass.

**2- If gravity were as strong as it is now, but other forces were even weaker**

Well. I guess the rate of expansion of the universe would be even greater than it is now. And atoms would be extremely loosely bound. Chemical reactions would not exchange as much energy with the environment as they do now. Stars would be very much less brighter (as fusion would release far lesser energy than now). Also, fusion reactors would be very easy to build. Probably every home would have its own fusion reactor to provide it with electricity. Also, atomic bombs would be jokes, hardly releasing as much energy as a chemical bomb does, today.